# Why arguments is not defined in arrow function in ES6?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

For this code

```
var sum = () => {console.log(arguments); ... }
sum(2, 3)
```

Get error `Uncaught ReferenceError: arguments is not defined`.

Why `arguments` is not defined in arrow function?